# Is possible to JToolTip to stay on

Tags: java, swing

I want to have a `JLabel` and when the mouse is over, a small description to appear with a small button that will send you to the full description.
I created a custom ToolTip and were I added the small description and the button, but I can't find how to make the `JToolTip` stay on.
I would like that the label will stay for few sec after the mouse leaves the label.
And if possible to stay on while mouse it's on tooltip.

It is possible ? Or is another way to get this description ?
Ty for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToolTipManager`:

```
javax.swing.ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(2000); // in milliseconds
```

`ToolTipManager` is singleton, so you have to use `sharedInstance()` to get the instance. More information about the `ToolTipManager` is [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html).

Comment: I tried this, but when I move mouse out of the Jlabel, the ToolTip instantly disappear :(

Comment: The above method is used only to not remove the ToolTip when mouse motion is not changed.